# How do I print an object value by inputting the object key into the function parameter?

Tags: javascript

How do I print an object value by inputting the object key into the function parameter?

```
var z = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

var list = function(x){
  console.log(z.x);
};
```

For example if I input list(a) I would like the function to read it as console.log(z.a), and therefore output = 1

Comment: there must be a duplicate of this, I just can't find the right one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an argument as a `string` and use square brackets instead of `.`.

```js
var z = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

var list = function(x){
  console.log(z[x]);
};

list('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
z[a]

...

list('a')
```

Change the dot to an index and put `a` in quotation marks